# Unable to compile Oracle ADF in jenkins using maven on linux due to ojmake.exe

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

Unable to compile Oracle ADF using maven with jenkins hosted in linux. I'm getting an error with ojmake.exe saying "unable to execute binary"

Error log:

> [INFO] /home/devops/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojmake.exe: /home/devops/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojmake.exe: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is your input?

Comment: Linux doesn't tend to run files called "something.exe" are you sure you've got the correct version of JDeveloper? (i.e. is there a possibility you've downloaded the Windows version" ?

Comment: I have a similar problem trying to execute ojmake.exe on a Linux Server. Same solution as the colleague described, but different error message: ERRORLEVEL = 126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!! Issue is resolved by replacing the ojmake.exe with ojmake file in all the pom.xml files in source code, I have to do it as Jenkins is installed on Linux OS. Jdeveloper provides multiple types of ojmake files, check the type of file with linux command 'file' and check if it is linux executable.

Note: I have installed jdeveloper on jenkins server to compile and deploy the Oracle ADF application source code.

There is no issue with installed java version: java version "1.8.0_162" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)